Please help me find this alien human male/humanoid catlike alien female fiction
I read it in English in September 2023 but it was posted years prior. It may have been on the Royal Road website, but that's just a guess.
There was this human male protagonist whose name might be Jake who had a AI sister and lived in a spaceship controlled by her since the murder of their father/creator in a failed attempt at sparking a war between AIs and humans. He seems to have some PTSD from witnessing the murder and travels through space pointlessly.
In one of his trips he becomes stranded on a planet inhabited by a catlike tall humanoid species with the lifespan of 200 years, but still living in the bronze age.
When he comes out of the ship to look for mineral resources (there's not enough fuel for him to leave the planet) he comes across a alien woman tied to a pole as an offering from the villagers (they'd seen the ship flying and thought it had some godlike or supernatural causes).
She is hostile towards him but ends up fainting due to the cold and wounds. He then takes her to the ship's med bay and soon she wakes up confused by the display of so much metal, which would be impossible to obtain even if he was one of the richest kings in that planet. The AI manages to create a translator implant for them.
They end up forming a partnership, as he is able to mine metals and she knows where he can refine it.
As the time passes, he forms a relationship with the villagers and they begin to build a base camp to facilitate the mining process. He and the woman form a relationship and end up saving and adopting a kidnapped princess. Later on they adopt a giant wolf-like three eyed puppy whose parents and siblings they've killed.
The last part I remember reading they were beginning form an alliance with a neighboring village which was tormented by the wolf-like mated pair they managed to kill.

https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/38682/of-men-and-dragons-book-1#:~:text=Jack%20crash%2Dlanded%20on%20a,are%20steering%20clear%20of%20it.

I found it, it's "Of Men and Dragons" from DrBlackJack21 on reddit

Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
